# Connecting to a mysql server remotely using Raspi giving error 2003 (111)

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, raspbian, digital-ocean, raspberry-pi3

I am currently attempting to use a Raspi 3 to connect to a mysql server and send data. Whenever I attempt to connect to the server, there is a few minutes of waiting at

```
mysql -u [username] -h [ip-address of server] -p
Enter Password:
```

This raspi is connected via ethernet to the network at my workplace. Whenever I attempt to connect, i get this error message after a while of waiting:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '[ip-address of server]' (111)
```

How would I go about fixing this so the raspi can connect.

Comment: mysql server should be set to allow remote connections. bind-address must be removed if added in mysql settings... user must be allowed to access remotely. firewall on the server should allow mysql port for remote access.  more, if Centos SeLinux might be disallowing it.... The problem shouldn't be in the "Raspi" server but the other unknown server that mysql server is installed. I tried to add what I would check first.

Comment: Definitely make sure that user has % access (or allow only client IP for better security) , not localhost only. Retry, if not working then check /etc/mysql/my.cnf (or another path according to your system) and comment out if there is bind-address=127.0.0.1 line. Save it and restart mysql server. Then test, if not working then disable firewall then test. If working after disabling firewall then enable firewall back and allow tcp 3306 (default mysql port) for mysql. Next thing is SeLinux but only if it is in Centos and it is enabled. Hope these help to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Connect as root to Your mysql/mariadb server and launch below query

```
GRANT ALL ON DatabaseName.* to DatabaseUser@ClientIpAddress IDENTIFIED BY 'UserPassword'
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "DatabaseUser";
```

for example:

```
GRANT ALL ON temp.* to 'admin2'@'192.168.8.141' IDENTIFIED BY 'rUUm432lkj49';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "admin2";
```

if you need grant access for all computers from scope

```
GRANT ALL ON temp.* to 'admin2'@'192.168.8.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'rUUm432lkj49';
```